# Getting JavaScript JSON string to populate DataTable

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I have a java function that gets a JSON string of data from a Servlet in Java. I am trying to use that data to populate a datatable (http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

This is the way that the DataTables website instructs users to populate datatables:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );
```

And this is the javascript method that calls the doPost method in my servlet to generate and return the JSON:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { // When the HTML DOM is ready loading, then execute the following function...
    //$('#somebutton').click(function() { // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somebutton" and assign the following function to its "click" event...
    var bodyContent = $.ajax({
      url : "DAOserv",
      global : false,
      type : "POST",
      data : "name=value",
      dataType : "json",
      async : false,
      success : function() {
                  console.log("ok");
                  alert("ok");  
                }
    }).responseText;
    console.log(bodyContent);
  });
</script>
```

How can I get the JSON string in `var bodyContent` to populate the datatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you're not really doing AJAX; when you do:

```
var bodyContent = $.ajax({
    url : "DAOserv",
    global : false,
    type : "POST",
    data : "name=value",
    dataType : "json",
    async : false,
    success : function() {
            console.log("ok");
            alert("ok");    
}).responseText;
```

You set `async: false` ... but AJAX stands for **Asynchonous** Javascript and XML.  With an AJAX approach the following happens:

1. You start the request by doing `$.ajax`
2. The server takes however long to respond; the user's browser is not locked up during this time
3. When the server responds the `success` callback you defined gets called

With your approach

1. You start the request by doing `$.ajax`
2. The user's browser is locked up while waiting for a response
3. When the server responds your code (after the `$.ajax` call) is invoked.

To make your code actual AJAX do this instead:

```
var bodyContent = $.ajax({
    url : "DAOserv",
    global : false,
    type : "POST",
    data : "name=value",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(responseText) {
            bodyContent = responseText
    }
});
```

Of course, once the response comes back you also need to build your Data Table, so what you really want is:

```
    success : function(responseText) {
                $('#example').dataTable( {
                    "data": responseText
                });
    }
```

(Or something to that effect; I forget DataTable's exact syntax.)

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice about making AJAX serve its purpose! I'm still trying to figure out how to make the bodyContent JSON data populate a datatable.

Comment: One other point of clarification: DataTables has two modes (that we care about).  The first mode does the AJAX *through* DataTables, and that's the mode where you pass DataTables an URL as an ajax property.  That mode doesn't use jQuery directly at all ... and personally I'm not a fan of that mode.  What I have described above is technically not what DataTables would call its AJAX mode; from DataTables perspective the above code is just your standard non-AJAX mode of DataTables (as you're doing all the AJAX outside of DataTables).

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [jQuery.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). The data returned from server in first argument of `success` callback. Also note that all manipulations with this data whould be inside this callback. I guess you should additionally check `status` argument:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bodyContent = null;
    $.ajax({
        url : "DAOserv",
        global : false,
        type : "POST",
        data : "name=value",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "data": $.parseJSON(data),
                "columns": [
                    { "title": "Engine" },
                    { "title": "Browser" },
                    { "title": "Platform" },
                ]
            });   
         });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE** To populate data server should respond with JSON encoded array of data and you should parse it and pass to dataTable as it noted [here](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html).

Comment: This does not answer the question. I'm wondering how to use that data (in this case the data in the bodyContent variable) to populate the Datatable.